# Issue with store when moving actionTypes into a constants file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

My store works perfectly fine when I define my actionTypes at the top of action.js, but when I move them to their own ActionTypes.js constants file and import, my redux store stops working.

My store works when *action.js* looks like

```
export const CHANGE_TEXT = 'CHANGE_TEXT';

// actionCreators
export function changeText(text) {
  return { 
    type: CHANGE_TEXT,
    text };
}
```

But when I move them to their own constants file everything stops working:

*action.js*

```
import { CHANGE_TEXT } from '../constants/ActionTypes'

// actionCreators
export function changeText(text) {
   return { 
     type: CHANGE_TEXT,
     text };
    }
```

*ActionTypes.js*

```
// actionTypes
export const CHANGE_TEXT = 'CHANGE_TEXT';
```

There isn't an error with the import path of the *ActionTypes.js* as I get no errors or console output suggesting an error. Just no item in the store.

Might be important to note that I haven't console logged the store, I output in a Text component as a javascript object (I think that's what it's called, sorry) eg. {Store.getState().changeText}. There may be an error in what I've just written as I'm editing this question on my mobile and going from memory. 
But, this works when I have it all in a single action.js file, but when I move the actionTypes to a constants file then it doesn't.

Comment: What does "everything stops working" mean? Do you get an error? What does it say? At a first glance this looks fine, but it could be a thousand different things... Wrong path in the import, a problem with the modules configuration, etc. Unless you give us more context, we will be shouting in the dark...

Comment: @Josep I've edited my post to hopefully give more clarity. Working = string output on screen within a Text component, no working = empty string (the initial state). There are no errors during runtime nor console logs

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with having them in the same file have you seen https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux I know it doesn’t answer your question but I find this set up much easier

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us the code of your reducer? I'm specially interested in the way that the action is being imported into the reducer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is my shot in the dark. If I had to make a guess of what's happening here it would be this:

Notice that with the old code you were doing:

```js
export const CHANGE_TEXT = 'CHANGE_TEXT';
```

from the `action.js` file, yes? And now you are importing `CHANGE_TEXT` from another file into `action.js`.

However, you are not exporting `CHANGE_TEXT` from `action.js` anymore, and before it was being exported from there, right?.

So, lets imagine that in your reducer you forgot to update the import, and that from the reducer you are still importing the action from `action.js`. What would it happen in that case? Well, the import wouldn't crash, it would just import `CHANGE_TEXT` as undefined and the reducer would stop working because it wouldn't match with the `type` of the action, because you would be trying to match it with `undefined`.

If I had to make a guess, this would be it... But it could be a thousand other things.

Comment: It was as simple as that! Thank you! I had a long day at work and when I came home to work on this my brain just wasn't working.

Presumably in my `reducer.js` I import from `constants/actionTypes.js` as well? That's what I've currently done. Or is there a way to export the import of the actionTypes in `actions.js`?